# python os.path.join on windows ignores first path element?

Tags: python, windows, path, operating-system

Consider the following:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> import os
>>> settings.VIRTUAL_ENV
'C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos'
>>> settings.EXTRA_BASE
'/oneclickcos/'
>>> os.path.join(settings.VIRTUAL_ENV,settings.EXTRA_BASE)
'/oneclickcos/'
```

As you can imagine, I neither expect nor want the concatenation of `'C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos'` and `'/oneclickcos/'` to be `'/oneclickcos/'`.

Oddly enough, reversing the path components once again shows python ignoring the first path component:

```
>>> os.path.join(settings.EXTRA_BASE,settings.VIRTUAL_ENV)
'C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos'
```

While this works something like expected:

```
>>> os.path.join('/foobar',settings.VIRTUAL_ENV,'barfoo')
'C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos\\barfoo'
```

I am of course, running on Windows (Windows 7), with the native python.

Why is this happening, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's pretty much how `os.path.join` is defined (quoting the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)):

> If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away

And I'd say it's usually a good thing, as it avoids creating invalid paths. If you want to avoid this behavior, don't feed it absolute paths. Yes, starting with a slash qualifies as absolute path. A quick and dirty solution is just removing the leading slash (`settings.EXTRA_BASE.lstrip('/')` if you want to do it programmatically).

Comment: OK, thanks, but in what sense is '/foo/' an absolute path on windows? This strikes me as surprising, and platform-inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: It's a drive-absolute path. It would actually make sense to keep the drive letter from the first element: os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Marcin', '\\oneclickos\\') -> 'C:\\oneclickos\\' but that's not how it works.

Comment: It isn't inconsistent at all if you ask me. Starting with a directory seperator means absolute path on many (all?) other platforms as well. You may object to the lack of a drive letter, but my memory and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style) say it's perfectly valid and simply refers to an absolute path on the same drive.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the leading `/` from the second string:

```
>>> os.path.join('C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos', 'oneclickos/')
'C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/oneclickcos\\oneclickos/'
```

This is because `os.path.join` discards all previous components once it meets an absolute path, and `/oneclickos/` *is an absolute path*.

Here's an excerpt from the doc of `os.path.join`:

> Join one or more path components intelligently. If any component is an
>   absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the
>   previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining
>   continues. [...]